# iOS7 issue with UISearchBar placeholder text alighment

Tags: ios, ios7, uisearchbar, placeholder

Hi it's strange behavior in `UISearchBar` placeholder text alignment while that `UISearchbar` non-edit mode but that disply fine at editing mode.In non-Edit mode that placeholder text position not displying as center, that text display bit up-side in to `UISearchbar` like bellow screenshot.

**Non-Editing Mode placeholder Looks like:**

[image]

**Editing Mode placeholder Looks like:**

[image]

As you can see First screenshot that text display bit up-side not look's like second screenshot Center. So i want to make this place Holder text center as search icon **Y** position.

I just setting search Bar Placeholder text using basic way:

```
 [self.srcbar setPlaceholder:@"Please Enter search Text"];
```

Please help me in this how can i fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

What you have described, is technically the default behavior for the search bar. If you'd like to get the text to slide over a bit when editing, you can adjust, in Interface Builder, the offset of the search bar. I've included a screen shot of xcode and the simulator to show you the difference at run time. See the image here: [image].

Comment: thank you for reply but actually problem is i used on textFiled Category that effect this UISearchBar text-filed so i did some change in this category then problem solve.